# Specifying dtype for parquet partition fields with dask.dataframe.read_parquet

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet, pyarrow

I have a parquet dataset structured like:

```
/path/to/dataset/a=True/b=1/data.parquet
/path/to/dataset/a=False/b=1/data.parquet
/path/to/dataset/a=True/b=2/data.parquet
/path/to/dataset/a=False/b=2/data.parquet
...
```

how do i specify the dtypes of partition fields (here, `a` and `b`) when calling `dd.read_parquet` on a directory like this?

i am using the `pyarrow` engine. do i need to specify a kwarg for a pyarrow function? if so, what would this be?

or, can i just call `astype(dict(a="bool", b="int"))` or something similar?

later on in my code, I am calling `DataFrame.query` to filter values, so dtype is important for boolean values, for example.

Comment: You certainly can coerce columns to specified data types using [`dask.dataframe.Dataframe.astype`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.astype.html) - the dict call syntax you use works just fine. But whether this can be specified on read is a good question too.

Comment: If you are using pyarrow as the underlying engine you can pass a `partitioning` argument https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#different-partitioning-schemes to document the schema of the partition. `dask.dataframe.read_parquet` will pass that argument along if you provide it (see **kwargs doc in https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.read_parquet.html)

Comment: @0x26res , this sounds like the write answer. Please add a complete solution of how you would write this in code for the given case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `pyarrow` as the underlying engine you can pass a [partitioning argument](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#different-partitioning-schemes) to specify the schema of the partition.

`dask.dataframe.read_parquet` will pass that argument along if you provide it. See `**kwargs` in the [doc](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.read_parquet.html).

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

partitioning = ds.partitioning(
    pa.schema([pa.field("a", pa.bool_()), pa.field('b', pa.int32())]),
    flavor="hive"
)
dd.read_parquet(directory="/path/to/dataset/", engine='pyarrow', partitioning=partitioning)
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work for me. i can create a dask dataframe, but if i call `df.head()` on the result, i get an error: `TypeError: 'pyarrow._dataset.HivePartitioning' object is not subscriptable`. it seems like this is related to this dask issue: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/8650 which apparently was fixed 2 months ago but... i'm getting the same error.

Comment: also, I think the correct way to provide these pyarrow kwargs is not to provide `partitioning=` directly in the `dd.read_parquet` call but rather to nest it inside a dict whose keys are the various pyarrow functions... eg, `datasets=dict(partitioning=...)` for the `pyarrow.datasets` API.